# Format HTTP links

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, links

I have a custom page template creating an xml feed found on a WP page at http://example.com/xml/

I am trying to access this xml document via Google Maps but it appears I need the actual file name like example.com/xml/example.xml

How can I add a .xml file extension at the end of the link http://example.com/xml/ ?

**EDIT:**
I am using a page template in my theme to display the output of XML. The XML part is probably irrelevant. What it comes down to I guess is how do I assign a specific file extension off of a page template such as /example.xml

Comment: I'm not the one who gave you a down vote, but may I suggest that you elaborate a little more on your question. Which plugin (or method) creates the .xml? The more details, the more likely someone is to help you.

Comment: I am using a page template in my theme to display the output of XML.  The XML part is probably irrelevant. What it comes down to I guess is how do I assign a specific file extension off of a page template such as /example.xml

Comment: Might I suggest that you add this comment and the code to your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the extension is irrelevant.

When your page is returned, WordPress is setting the content-type for the file in the headers as `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.  This tells any consuming application that the content is HTML, *not* XML.

You need to force WordPress to send the appropriate headers when outputting the XML.

This content type is set by `bloginfo('html_type')` and is often copied into a `<meta />` tag in your blog header as well.  You can add a filter to hook in to this value:

```
add_filter( 'option_html_type', 'my_xml_override' );
function my_xml_override( $type ) {
    // First, check to make sure you're on the right page template:
    if ( /* On XML template */ ) {
        $type = 'text/xml';
    }

    return $type;
}
```

I leave detecting the page template as an excerise for you ... mostly because I don't have the time to test it for you.  But if you look around, there are [plenty of tutorials](http://archive.extralogical.net/2007/06/detect-template/) available.